# How do you make Ubuntu permanent on a laptop's hardrive that has no other OS?

Tags: usb-installation

I have a toshiba satellite and the only thing that's letting me get to you all is this flash drive hooked to my computer with ubuntu on it, but the second I take it out the whole ubuntu is gone and I have to start the whole process over again.I deleted windows altogether before completely installing ubuntu which was a total mistake. Please help It has no other OS to fall back on

Comment: Possible duplicate of every installation guide for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

double click on the "install Ubuntu" and follow directions?  Or alternatively, here's a video equivalent that's a bit more use friendly.

A better guide:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lt5I-FoG7dE